# mass insert laravel for many records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve data from sql table A, modify some columns then insert the modified columns into sql table B.

However my issue is that when I use:

```
    $customer= new Customer;
    $fakecustomer= new Fakecustomer;

            $fake_customer_name_records = $fakecustomer->get()->toArray();

               foreach($fake_customer_name_records as $record){

            //process columns for each record

                 $fake_customer_name_records_arry[]=array(
                  'last_name'=>$last_name,
                  'first_name'=>$first_name,
                  'home_phone'=>$phonenumber,
                  );
}

            $customer->insert($fake_customer_name_records_arry);
```

It can only insert around 1000 records.  Is there a way in Laravel for me to process about 60,000 records?

Thanks

Comment: Might be helpful if you tell us what happens when you try to process 60,000?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to use the "chunk" option here, and process records in "chunks". It's more native way, to my opinion. Here's what docs say :

> **Chunking Results**
>
> If you need to process a lot (thousands) of Eloquent records, using
>   the chunk command will allow you to do without eating all of your RAM:
>
> ```
> User::chunk(200, function($users)
> {
>     foreach ($users as $user)
>     {
>         //
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> The first argument passed to the method is the number of records you
>   wish to receive per "chunk". The Closure passed as the second argument
>   will be called for each chunk that is pulled from the database.

Link to read more : [click](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage)

Comment: Maybe you can help me. I want to implement chunk to my case. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487769/how-to-insert-big-data-on-the-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra variable and sum 1 every iteration, when reaches 1000 (or lower) execute 'insert' and reset the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the query log with `DB::disableQueryLog();` ? I had the same problem and this prety much solved it.

Also, when working with migrations or some process that's going to take a lot of time try to create a `command` instead of trying to do it with a `controller`.