# How to insert big data on the laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, insert, bigdata, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel 5.6

My script to insert big data is like this :

```
...
$insert_data = [];
foreach ($json['value'] as $value) {
    $posting_date = Carbon::parse($value['Posting_Date']);
    $posting_date = $posting_date->format('Y-m-d');
    $data = [
        'item_no'                   => $value['Item_No'],
        'entry_no'                  => $value['Entry_No'], 
        'document_no'               => $value['Document_No'],
        'posting_date'              => $posting_date,
        ....
    ];
    $insert_data[] = $data;
}
\DB::table('items_details')->insert($insert_data);
```

I have tried to insert 100 record with the script, it works. It successfully insert data

But if I try to insert 50000 record with the script, it becomes very slow. I've waited about 10 minutes and it did not work. There exist error like this :

```
504 Gateway Time-out
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can chunk the data by using Laravel chunk functions. 
Maybe this post will help you [insert big data](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-insert-millions-of-records-in-laravel-51)

Comment: You could also use Laravels queue system and just creat 50,000 jobs for each insertion. But if you insist on sending large quantities, you need to increase the PHP timeout (you will want to google what your server stack is for instructions)

Comment: Yeah, chunk won't really help you in this case. `chunk` will help solve issues with memory usage, but not for your app running for too long. Like Rob suggested, look into using the queue and creating a job fo each individual item. Then you can run a heap of workers to crunch the data for you.

Comment: @Dwight I'm still confused. Try to answer this question with a detail answer(with the script)

Comment: @Rob Fonseca I'm still confused. Try to answer this question with a detail answer(with the script)

Comment: @Dennis I'm confused to implement to my case

Comment: @SuccessMan try to read the docs of laravel, it will help you a lot to understand the use of queues. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues

Comment: @Dwight thanks, I didn't know that, I learned something too today ;)

Comment: Have you considered using a queue?

Comment: @haakym Yeah. I also consider it

Comment: @haakym Please answer this question using queue. So there exist some option

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As it was stated, chunks won't really help you in this case if it is a time execution problem. I think that bulk insert you are trying to use cannot handle that amount of data , so I see 2 options:

1 - Reorganise your code to properly use chunks, this will look something like this:

```
$insert_data = [];

foreach ($json['value'] as $value) {
    $posting_date = Carbon::parse($value['Posting_Date']);

    $posting_date = $posting_date->format('Y-m-d');

    $data = [
        'item_no'                   => $value['Item_No'],
        'entry_no'                  => $value['Entry_No'], 
        'document_no'               => $value['Document_No'],
        'posting_date'              => $posting_date,
        ....
    ];

    $insert_data[] = $data;
}

$insert_data = collect($insert_data); // Make a collection to use the chunk method

// it will chunk the dataset in smaller collections containing 500 values each. 
// Play with the value to get best result
$chunks = $insert_data->chunk(500);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk)
{
   \DB::table('items_details')->insert($chunk->toArray());
}
```

This way your bulk insert will contain less data, and be able to process it in a rather quick way.

2 - In case your host supports runtime overloads, you can add a directive right before the code starts to execute :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 120 ) ; // time in seconds

$insert_data = [];

foreach ($json['value'] as $value)
{
   ...
}
```

To read more go to the official [docs](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: With the second option you can still use chunks to avoid the big bulk chunk

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it. Please update your answer with chunk. So there exist some option

Comment: I had try your script. There exist error like this : `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, object given`

Comment: @SuccessMan just use the ```->toArray()``` method

Comment: UPDATED ^^. Check the chunk

Comment: Ok. Your second option, it is the same as the answer in my question.  What's different? Actually I have added this `ini_set('max_execution_time', 120 ) ;` too?

Comment: @VitKos stackoverflow doesn't support markdown you have to indent your text for code blocks

Comment: @SuccessMan you can use it with whatever code you like, your version or chunk version - you decide. I just pointed out how to enlarge the execution time in runtime

Comment: @Vit Kos I had try your option use chunk and it works. So I receive your answer. Thanks

Comment: @VitKos you don't need to convert the array to a collection to use chunk you can just use php chunk | ```$chunks = array_chunk(insert_data,500)```. this way you dont need to convert back to an array when you interact with the DB.

Answer (score 5):

It makes no sense to use an array and then convert it to a collection.

We can get rid of arrays.

```
$insert_data = collect();

foreach ($json['value'] as $value) {
    $posting_date = Carbon::parse($value['Posting_Date']);

    $posting_date = $posting_date->format('Y-m-d');

    $insert_data->push([
        'item_no'                   => $value['Item_No'],
        'entry_no'                  => $value['Entry_No'], 
        'document_no'               => $value['Document_No'],
        'posting_date'              => $posting_date,
        ....
    ]);
}

foreach ($insert_data->chunk(500) as $chunk)
{
   \DB::table('items_details')->insert($chunk->toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is very good and very Fast Insert data solution

```
$no_of_data = 1000000;
$test_data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $no_of_data; $i++){
    $test_data[$i]['number'] = "1234567890";
    $test_data[$i]['message'] = "Test Data";
    $test_data[$i]['status'] = "Delivered";
}
$chunk_data = array_chunk($test_data, 1000);
if (isset($chunk_data) && !empty($chunk_data)) {
   foreach ($chunk_data as $chunk_data_val) {
    DB::table('messages')->insert($chunk_data_val);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the code below to check the update or insert data of 11 thousand rows. I hope it useful for you.

```
$insert_data = [];
for ($i=0; $i < 11000; $i++) { 
    $data = [
        'id' =>'user_'.$i,
        'fullname' => 'Pixs Nguyen',
        'username' => 'abc@gmail.com',
        'timestamp' => '2020-03-23 08:12:00',
    ];
    $insert_data[] = $data;
}

$insert_data = collect($insert_data); // Make a collection to use the chunk method

// it will chunk the dataset in smaller collections containing 500 values each. 
// Play with the value to get best result
$accounts = $insert_data->chunk(500);
// In the case of updating or inserting you will take about 35 seconds to execute the code below
for ($i=0; $i < count($accounts); $i++) { 
    foreach ($accounts[$i] as $key => $account)
    {
        DB::table('yourTable')->updateOrInsert(['id'=>$account['id']],$account);
    }
}
// In the case of inserting you only take about 0.35 seconds to execute the code below
foreach ($accounts as $key => $account)
{
    DB::table('yourTable')->insert($account->toArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding time comparison too.