# How to optimize Postgres for bulk insert data?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a table that must be optimized for bulk insert data over 100 00 rows for execution time.

[Table columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3NAB.png)

I try to insert data using PHP, where each row is element of array:

```
   $dataset = [["columnindex" => 1, "rowindex" => 2, "type" => "num", "value" => 400], ...]
```

Problem is when I try to insert array with 100 rows the Postgres does not work, also PDO does not return any errors.

I use insert from Laravel:

```
 SessionPrepared::insert($dataset);
```

If to slice array it is adeed to db:

```
 $dataset = array_slice($dataset, 0, 10);
```

Comment: Show your code, please to debug.

Comment: I use insert from Laravel: `SessionPrepared::insert($dataset);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert big data on the laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487769/how-to-insert-big-data-on-the-laravel)